# Change The WordPress template to

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a blog in WordPress (version 2.8.4) .

I need to change the template of blog so that i can have my own template.
so which template file i need to change to define template for my blog?

Comment: This can changed in Appearance - Themes. If you created your own theme, you should know this. OR even just by using Wordpress, this should be one of the first things to know about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003816/wordpress-theme-development-quick-start

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

This is very well documented all around the internet...